# How can I install multiple JDK versions using opscode java cookbook

Tags: chef-infra

How can I install multiple JDK versions using opscode java cookbook (flavor = oracle)

Answer (score 0):

Try the [java_ark](https://github.com/socrata-cookbooks/java#java_ark) resource provided by the cookbook:

```rb
# install jdk6 from Oracle
java_ark "jdk" do
    url 'http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u29-b11/jdk-6u29-linux-x64.bin'
    checksum  'a8603fa62045ce2164b26f7c04859cd548ffe0e33bfc979d9fa73df42e3b3365'
    app_home '/usr/local/java/default'
    bin_cmds ["java", "javac"]
    action :install
end
```

You can probably call the `java_ark` resource multiple times (with different parameters) in your wrapper cookbook.

Comment: I tried using that but it didn't work. Also looking at documentation it seems like java_ark is now deprecated https://github.com/socrata-cookbooks/java#resourcesproviders

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did to have both oracle JDK7 and JDK8 on my nodes (RHEL).

JDK7 will be set as the default (The $JAVA_HOME points to this version of JDK i,e 7).

Specify the below in your `/attributes/default.rb` file

```
default['java']['install_flavor'] = 'oracle'
default['java']['jdk_version'] = '7'
default['java']['oracle']['accept_oracle_download_terms'] = true
```

And then put in the below lines in your wrapper cookbook

```
include_recipe 'java'

#adding the below for the JDK8 installation
java_ark "oracle-jdk8-x86_64" do
  url node['java']['jdk']['8']['x86_64']['url']
  checksum node['java']['jdk']['8']['x86_64']['checksum']
  app_home '/usr/lib/jvm/oracle-jdk8-x86_64'
  action :install
end
```

The above code will install JDK7 and JDK8 under /usr/lib/jvm/  (for RHEL/Fedora). Please refer the [java cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/java) for the details on the directory for JAVA_HOME based on the platform.

This a link to a working example that i referred

https://github.com/erichelgeson/jenkins-chef-dsl/blob/master/recipes/build-jdks.rb